# Using InvokeRestAPI to send form data

Tags: azure-pipelines, multipartform-data

Trying to send form data in Azure DevOps's InvokeRestAPI task which looks like the following:

[ADO Pipeline Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qPi2.png)

but the endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx) keeps coming back with this message:

> Response: An error was encountered while processing request. Exception: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.

How to format the InvokeRestAPI task for the endpoint to see it as an actual form-data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested to modify the `Content-Type`  as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and edited the request body as in the sample YAML below; I managed to call the Rest API.

```
jobs:
- job:
  pool: server
  steps:
  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
      serviceConnection: 'AzureAPISvcCnn'
      method: 'POST'
      headers: |
        {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$(CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=$(CLIENT_SECRET)&resource=https://storage.azure.com/'
      waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

[image: Invoke Rest API]

Comment: Thx @alvin Zha the code above still returns the same error, as grant_type is not being sent as form-data.

Request body: {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "parameter_from_payload": "test1",
  "parameter_name": "test2"
}
    Response Code: 0
    Response: An error was encountered while processing request. Exception: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'. ....

Comment: Thx a lot for the reminder. I have revised the YAML and hope it would be helpful to you. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, that is now no longer complaining about 'grant_type'.

Much appreciated